# Как можно оптимизировать код с множеством условий?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал вот такой вод кусок кода для одной программы, но учитывая количества условий его размер получается очень большим, можно ли оптимизировать его?

```
# Функция загрузки первого задания
def task1(self):
    if self.directory_task == "default":
        self.directory_task = os.getcwd() + "/task"
        if self.task_type == "planned":
            if self.task1_type == "img":
                if self.auto_img_size == True:
                    pass
                elif self.auto_img_size == False:
                    pass
                else:
                    pass
            elif self.task1_type == "text":
                pass
            else:
                pass
        elif self.task_type == "base":
            if self.task1_type == "img":
                if self.auto_img_size == True:
                    pass
                elif self.auto_img_size == False:
                    pass
                else:
                    pass
            elif self.task1_type == "text":
                pass
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Как это делать на пайтоне пока не знаю, но у вас явный дубликат кода `if self.task1_type == "img":` Это бы вынести в отдельную функцию и передавать в нее параметры.

Comment: если вы проверяете `self.auto_img_size` на предмет `True/False`, т.е. булевые значения, то зачем там еще один `else` ? Вы ожидаете помимо `True/False` еще какое-то значение?

Comment: @Dmitry Видимо ожидает None, но его не встречает

Comment: @Dmitry else на случай ввода в файле .ini не корректного значения, что бы программа не закрылась, а передала эту ошибку в отчет

Comment: Без знания что именно вы делаете в тех местах, где поставили `pass`, довольно сложно что-то советовать. Может быть это всё можно в одну какую-то функцию поместить и вызывать её с разными параметрами. Может ещё как-то можно зарефакторить или сгруппировать, но так ничего непонятно.

Comment: т.е. предлагаете оптимизировать отсутствующий код? Ну если у вас блоки if self.task1_type == "img": одинаковые, то можно объединить проверки на self.task_type == "planned" и self.task_type == "base". Если разные, то ничего тут сократить нельзя

Comment: @Эникейщик понял, тут именно проблема сокращения не кода который будет после условий, а именно самих условий